# Spring Thymeleaf server-side pagination

Tags: spring, pagination, datatables, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I've been trying to implement a sever-side pagination for my project using Spring and Thymeleaf, I was able  to read things about how I can make this posible, one is through the use of dandelion datatables wherein I was able to make the integration successful but only in the client side. The second one i tried is using an example I found at http://www.opencodez.com/java/datatable-with-spring-boot.html which was successful but was a bit complicated. Other examples I find are from this and other sites are old, I need a recent example on how I could implement server-side pagination in Spring using thymeleaf and JPA. It would also a big help if it would involve the use of JQuery datatables because of its features.

Comment: Link does not work.

Comment: oh here- http://www.opencodez.com/java/datatable-with-spring-boot.htm

Comment: Whats wrong with the opencodez example you provided? While you might find it a bit complicated it does showcase the necessary pieces and given you said it was successful it would seem like it answers your question

Comment: I also uploaded the sample that I was able to create here https://github.com/ergumayagay/datatables-server-side.git

Comment: @SeanCarroll I'm looking for something much simpler, something with less code, given I'm quite new to Spring development. I'm also looking for suggestions for other things I could try.

Comment: Most of the code in that link is taking the request that comes from dataTables and building a representation of it on the server to then do a query. You can't really get around that when doing server side processing with datatables. You will find something similar in the dandelion codebase. When I've implemented this in the past I personally preferred to put the code in an argument resolver but that code still needs to exist somewhere

Comment: @SeanCarroll maybe your solution is less complex? can you give me at least a sample

Comment: I dont have a public sample at the moment but it might be something I can throw up github, assuming no one else provides an example. I would also consider looking at the dandelion code (https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables). Primary code is found in DatatablesCriterias and they provide a argument resolver as well DatatablesCriteriasMethodArgumentResolver.

Comment: @SeanCarroll Oh it looks partly the same with the example provided by opencodez, based on the answer on this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363646/spring-jpa-repositories-generic-find-with-dandelion-datatablecriterias question I could use Spring's JPARepository to ease the integration with dandelion datatables, do you have any idea on how I could make this work? I'm looking forward for the sample. Thanks in advance

Comment: The sample in that stackoverflow questions looks like it might come from https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables-samples/tree/master/datatables-thymeleaf-ajax

Comment: @SeanCarroll I'm actually about to try the sample, the answers though seem pointing out the use of Spring data repository instead of the JPA repository provided by the sample.

Comment: I've used spring data jpa with datatables and it's similar

Comment: @SeanCarroll can you provide me with the right things to read to help me further?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490820/spring-thymeleaf-how-to-implement-pagination-for-a-list

Comment: related: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/implement-bootstrap-pagination-with-spring-data-and-thymeleaf.html . Did you try to follow this tutorial?

Comment: related: http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with Spring-Data's pagination and the Thymeleaf dialect here https://github.com/jpenren/thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect/

Should do exactly what you want I think.

Comment: I'll definitely try this one. Thanks.